# AVAudioConverter buffers are over-retained in a DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform context

Tags: swift, macos, concurrency, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I have an audio analysis tool which I’m trying to parallelise, but it uses an escalating amount of heap space when working on a set of audio files.

It turns out that when I use `AVAudioConverter.convert(to:error:withInputFrom:)` inside a `concurrentPerform` block, a large amount of the memory associated with each conversion is retained until the very end of the concurrent performance, rather than being released at the end of each iteration’s execution. As such, the memory usage climbs and climbs while a batch of files is processed, rather than staying effectively flat during parallel operations.

I’m assuming that this is some flaw in my code rather than a bug in either framework, and hope someone can help me find it. See below a simplified version of the code, which converts the same file an arbitrary number of times (rather than operating on a large batch of different files as is the case in my real application).
Any help appreciated!

```
let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)!

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1000) { index in

        let inputFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(filePath: "/path/to/some/song.m4a"))

        let inputFormat = inputFile.processingFormat
        let inputFrameCount = AVAudioFrameCount(inputFile.length)
        let inputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: inputFormat, frameCapacity: inputFrameCount)!

        try! inputFile.read(into: inputBuffer)

        let sampleRateCoefficient = inputFormat.sampleRate / outputFormat.sampleRate
        let outputFrameCount = UInt32(Double(inputFrameCount) / sampleRateCoefficient)
        let outputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: outputFrameCount)!

        let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputBuffer.format, to: outputFormat)!
        let converterInputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { _, outStatus in
            outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
            return inputBuffer
        }

        // If we just do some arbitrary work here, even big mallocs, memory usage is flat as everything is released at the end of the concurrentPerform closure.
        // But if we run this conversion, each iteration retains a big chunk of memory until they're all finished. :(

        converter.convert(
            to: outputBuffer,
            error: nil,
            withInputFrom: converterInputBlock
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing the convert call with an arbitrary large malloc or other hefty calculation, to see if there was some general problem with releasing the memory in that context, but it was released at the end of the iteration as expected. This seems to be specific to the behaviour of the convert call.

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to inspect the memory usage?

Comment: @ipmcc Yes. The allocations are multi-megabyte mallocs, not named types. Was there anything specific you wanted to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Looking closer at the debug memory graph it seemed that the `autoreleasepool` holding the audio buffer was too long-lived. I've not worked closely with these pools before but I was able to solve the memory issue by closely wrapping the conversion call in its own pool:

```
_ = autoreleasepool {
    converter.convert(
        to: outputBuffer,
        error: nil,
        withInputFrom: converterInputBlock
    )
}
```

This appears to correctly scope the lifetime of the buffers.